# Can hyper-V and esxi have a common publishing / orchestrating system?

Tags: vmware-esxi, hyper-v

I have a requirement , customer is using hyper-v as well esxi, but they want the template management and provisioning of the virtual machines or disk to be done using a single system. Can it be done? What technology will it require?

Comment: Check System Center Virtual Machine Manager. Handles both, Hyper-V and VMWare.

Answer (score 1):

The only one that stands out is [Microsoft System Center Virtual Machine Manager](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/system-center/vmm/overview?view=sc-vmm-1801), although does has it draw backs when using VMware, but will allow you to provision to both.

There are a few other tools out there for managing both, Veeam is good one it designed for backup but you can provision and migrate from either hyper-v or Vmware.

Personally depending on the setup of each of the hosts, clustered, vswitches, etc you are going to need to use the the dedicated consoles at some point to manage and administer. Trying to find an all encompassing control panel for both will only lead you to problems when new features come out.